# Append date and time to the std_out_file in jil

Tags: date, jobs, autosys

I have a job in Autosys. I want new log file to be created for its every run. Hence, I want to append date and time to the logfile name I am giving in std_out_file. Is there any way to do this other than creating a global variable  and then updating it everyday using another autosys job?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default to do this. You can use this:

```
\\logpath\%auto_job_name%.%autorun%.OUT.txt
```

This will create a run number and it will not overwrite the logs even if there are multiple runs a day. You can use the date/time that is when the file is created for sorting.